# Javascript Alerting DIV content on click button/url

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi so I'm trying to understand and learn Javascripting.
I was challenged to find out how to alert the content of each individual  onclick.
Using a loop.

So I started to scratch my head and try multiple approaches.
I did manage to get the  content alerted but unfortunately without a clickevent.

```
function raport()
document.querySelectorAll(".fake").forEach(div=>{
text+=div.textContent;
});
alert(text);
}
```

Used a query selector to search for the class name .fake followed by div=>text.div.textcontent
making variable text = to the div's content.
Upon loading the page, the browser succesfully alerts the div content as seen on the html page.

BUT when I try to use a onclick event to trigger the loop upon clicking a button..

Nothing happens..

I thought of adding a buton with a specific id combined with the code:

```
document.getElementById('demo').onclick = function() {raport()}
```

The HTML button:

```
<button id= "demo" onclick="raport()">Klik</button>
```

As a means to get it done, but I'm not getting any errors nor any alerts with the  content.

I also guess this isn't the most productive way to accomplish the challenge.
As I'm supposed to alert each individual 
Meaning that I would have copy the code with unique button id's and div classes to get the right results.

Any tips on how I could get the clickevent working?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's just a typo error, you didn't open `raport` bracket `{` and another possible error you din't create `text` variable

Answer (score 1):

Just as a demonstration then close the question, it is a typo error:

```js
let text ='';
function raport() {
  text = ''; // add this if you want clean variable everytime click, or just declare into function the variable
  document.querySelectorAll(".fake").forEach(div => {
    text += div.textContent;
  });
  alert(text);
}

document.getElementById('demo').onclick = function() {
  raport()
}
```

```html
<button id="demo" onclick="raport()">Klik</button>
<div class='fake'>Hello</div>
<div class='fake'>Man</div>
```

---

Example of your comment:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.fake').forEach(el =>{
  el.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    alert(el.textContent);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class='fake'>Hello</div>
<div class='fake'>Man</div>
<div class='fake'>test2</div>
```

Comment: This worked very well when I made all the div classes unique and copied the queryselectorall+ foreach for each individual unique div class. 

still trying to figure out how to use 1 loop for 1 div class repeated on a page with different text content. 

Example: <div class='d1'> Hello </div>
               <div class='d1'> World!</div> 

If I were to click on the div containing the text Hello, the output should be Alert(Hello)
And when I click on the div containing the text World! it should alert(World!)

Comment: I have been told this can be done using a simple for loop and or even a while loop. 

But I'm starting to doubt that's possible. 

Maybe by adding all textcontent from the div in to an array using the queryselectorAll? 
But than there's still the problem of identifying the clicked on div and it's content? 

document.getelementbyID? giving each div a unique ID but the same class? 

Finishing with a IF to determine the clicked on div id? 

Just thinking from novice perspective with little to no knowledge.

Comment: I create a new snippet in my answer you can see when you click into each div alert will be the textContent of div.

Comment: Wow! that's amazing! can this same principle be assigned to a for() loop?

Comment: Yes but why don't use a forEach?

Comment: Just trying to understand all forms of loops to get better perspective and understanding on how it all works.

Comment: Also it's a impressive compact code that does get the job done. 

But its functionality is still rather vague to me. 

It searches for the first css attribute like or equal to .fake. 
than for each  variable EL is equal or greater than el.eventlistener is equal or greater than alert(el.textcontent);

Comment: Actually querySelector searches exactly for the term, in this case all elements that have a `.fake` class, `forEach` will pass each element (callable with `el`) then adding a `click` event with `addEventListener`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239812/discussion-between-marten-philip-and-simone-rossaini).

Answer (score 1):

I always suggest delegation if you want to click each "fake"

And a map if you want to get a list of stuff

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() { // when the page loads
  const res = document.getElementById("res");
  const fakes = document.querySelectorAll("#demo .fake");
  document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains("fake")) {
      res.textContent = tgt.textContent;
    }
  });
  document.getElementById("klik").addEventListener("click", function() { 
    res.innerHTML = [...fakes] // cast the html collection to an array
      .map(fake => fake.textContent) // map the content
      .join(","); 
      
  })
});
```

```html
<div id="demo">
  <div class='fake'>Hello</div>
  <div class='fake'>Man</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="klik">Klik</button>
<hr/>
<div id="res"></div>
```